# Why does C give me a different answer than my calculator?

Tags: c, floating-point, division

I've run into an odd problem with this code:

`legibIndex = 206.385 - 84.6 * (countSylb / countWord) - 1.015 * (countWord / countSent);`

This is the calculation for the legibility index of a given text file.
Since this is a homework assignment, we were told what the Index should be (80, or exactly 80.3)

My syllable count, word count, and sentence count are all correct (they match up with the given numbers for the sample textfiles.

Even if I hardcode the numbers in, I do not get 80, even though I do when i put it into my caclulator exactly as seen. I can't imagine what is wrong.

Here is the equation we were given:

`Index = 206.835 - 84.6 * (# syllables/# words) - 1.015 * (# words/# sentences)`

As you can see, I just plugged in my variables (which are holding the correct values.
For reference, the values are : 55 Syllables, 40 Words, 4 Sentences, as given by the instructor. The values my program produces when ran is a Legibility Index of 112.

Am I missing some brackets, or what?
I'm stumped!

Comment: Index is an int, all of the other variables are ints. It make sense because you can't have 0.2 of a syllable, or 0.5 of a word.

But even if you put 

`206.835-84.6*(55/40)-1.015*(40/4)`
into the program (e.g. hard coding like I said), it does not produce the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, as **sparks** indicated and Charles answered, it's a rounding issue caused by your data types. And I *bet* that was the point of the assignment. :-)

Comment: D'oh, integer division, thanks!

Comment: And No, T.J the assignment was a lot harder, thats like the little easy part to top things off, haha. Which is part of the reason I was getting frustrated. Knew it was something simple.

Comment: If you want to see the reason do int/int and look at your result, then do the same thing with floats. I believe gcc will always round towards 0 but I'm not sure if that is a compiler choice or if it is in the spec.

Comment: Yea, I know why that happens, it just didn't occur to me.

Comment: For this reason, any coding standard worth its salt would not permit the programmer to write compound expressions. Think about the ideal situation: single-stepping through the code one line at a time to confirm the calculation's progress. Zero bugs every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right off the bat, from the names (which include the word *count*) I'd guess that `countSylb`, `countSent`  and `countWord` are declared as integers, and therefore your divisions are doing integer arithmetic, truncating the decimal portions. Cast them to floats and that should fix it.

```
legibIndex = 206.385 - 84.6 * ((float)countSylb / ((float)countWord) - 
               1.015 * (((float)countWord / ((float)countSent);
```

Comment: Casting to `double` may produce better results.  Many C language gurus say to use `double` rather than float.

Comment: @Thomas,  If you know why this is so, could you elaborate ?

Comment: My understanding is the math library is coded as double precision and floating point constants are given the type `double`.  Also, `double` precision gives more accuracy than `float`.  `float` should only be used when memory is tight.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a data type issue where you're rounding because int/int = int instead of float.

If you cast to float or declare as float it should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Works here. Perhaps you're doing integer division instead of float division:

```
>>> def leg(syl, wor, sen):
...   return 206.835 - 84.6 * (float(syl) / wor) - 1.015 * (float(wor) / sen)
... 
>>> print leg(55, 40, 4)
80.36
```

Answer (score 1):

If your calculations inside the brackets are pure integer the calculation will drop the decimal parts and be rounded down ( same as using floor() ) which obviously will alter the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) issue. To be sure, group the things you think should happen first more than you already have.

**Edit** No, it isn't; using C's operator precedence I get 80.36. I expect **sparks** was right (and the first off the mark) that it's a data type problem and you're running into premature rounding.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in Haskell, I get the right answer (80.36000000000001).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that (# syllables/# words) comes to 1 if you're using integer arithmetic. If you make sure that you perform the calculation using floating point arithmetic (so # syllables/# words = 1.375), you should get the right answer out.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, your count variables are likely whole number integers, but your expression contains literal floating point numbers.  Casting those ints into floats will give the correct value.  You must also make sure that what you are storing the expression's result in (legibIndex) is also of type float.