# C program giving different answer than calculator

Tags: c

I'm trying this exercise from C Programming a Modern Approach by K.N. King and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The correct answer isn't available on the authors website. Here's the question:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AP5P.png

> Write a program that computes the volume of a sphere with a 10-meter
>   radius, using the formula v=4/3πr<sup>3</sup>. Write the fraction 4/3 as 4.0f/3.0f.
>   (Try writing it as 4/3. What happens?) *Hint:* C doesn't have an
>   exponention operator, so you'll need to multiply r by itself twice to
>   compute r<sup>3</sup>.

Note the correct output (as given by (4/3) * 3.14 * 1000) is 4186.6666...67, however my code outputs 41866.667969. I assume this is some sort of rounding error due to data types (at least from what I inferred from this question/answer [Why does C give me a different answer than my calculator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222569/why-does-c-give-me-a-different-answer-than-my-calculator))

Here's my code:

```
//Sphere computation
//Formula = v= 4.0f / 3.0f * 3.14 (pi) * r^3 (a = r*r, b = a*a)

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float volume, pi, fraction, radiusOne, radiusSquared, radiusCubed;

    radiusOne = 10.0f;
    pi = 3.14f;
    fraction = 4.0f / 3.0f;

    radiusSquared = radiusOne * radiusOne;
    radiusCubed = radiusSquared * radiusSquared;
    volume = fraction * pi * radiusCubed;

    printf("Volume: %f\n", volume);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You think PI is 3.14 ?

Comment: @PaulR: Of course pi isn't 3.14. Pi is 3.2, as demanded by the Indiana Pi Bill.

Comment: Try changing all `float`s to `double`s.

Comment: @TimČas: For simplicity, why not just 3?

Comment: @drum: If you're going to use "Legal Rounding", might as well round it to 4 then. Or go for broke and say it's 10.

Comment: use math.PI instead of 3.14

Comment: @RickardB. (Almost) true for C# (it should be `Math.PI`). For C it's `M_PI`.

Comment: When it comes to π, a classic approximation is `atan(1)*4`. A better approximation is probably `atan2(0, -1)` since you avoid multiplying the already imprecise number, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @PaulR Nah, was just using an approximation, don't really care how accurate pi is.

Comment: @unxnut thank you! was wondering why that was still going on.

Comment: @ClickRick
Thank you for telling me that!

Comment: @ClickRick: `M_PI` is non-standard.

Comment: pi can be quickly approximated as 355.0/113.0 which uses relatively simple math.  Then as @user3121023 indicated, your calculating the radiusCubed to the 4th power rather than the 3rd power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
radiusCubed = radiusSquared * radiusSquared;  //This makes it to the power of 4
```

with

```
radiusCubed = radiusSquared * radiusOne;    //This makes it to the power of 3
```

or

```
radiusCubed = radiusOne * radiusOne * radiusOne;   //This makes it to the power of 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is off by ten because these two lines are incorrect:

```
radiusSquared = radiusOne * radiusOne;
radiusCubed = radiusSquared * radiusSquared;
```

This computes R<sup>4</sup>, not R<sup>3</sup>, because R<sup>2</sup> * R<sup>2</sup> = R<sup>4</sup>.

You probably meant to write

```
radiusSquared = radiusOne * radiusOne;
radiusCubed = radiusSquared * radiusOne;
```

You can use `pow(R, 3)` to compute the answer, or simply `radiusCubed = radiusOne * radiusOne * radiusOne`.

Answer (score 1):

You have written

```
radiusSquared = radiusOne * radiusOne;
radiusCubed = radiusSquared * radiusSquared;
```

Given that radiusOne is initialised to 10, radiusSquared will be 100. Then when you multiply that by itself you produce the result that radiusCubed will be 10,000 instead of 1,000 which it should be.

Use this instead:

```
radiusCubed = radiusOne * radiusOne * radiusOne;
```

Where the question said

> you'll need to multiply r by itself twice

it meant this latter form, not that you should multiply it by itself, and then multiply that result by itself.

Part of the rounding issue is indeed related to the link in your question - using double-precision floating point rather than single-precision will pretty much eliminate that. Other rounding issues stem from your use of 3.14 as the approximation for pi rather than anything more precise. The correct value to use is the one defined in `math.h`

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer. On pi being an approximation, why when i enter the exact same numbers in my calculator do I get a different answer? I type '(4/3) * 3.14 * 10' into my calculator, and it gives a different answer to 'volume = fraction * pi * radiusCubed;' in my code. Edit: Figured this out, just had to change all the floats to doubles. Cheers to unxnut for the answer.